# What's the correct word for when you stop using a syllabus?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

When a certain course is no longer offered at the university, the syllabus is (obviously) no longer used. Is there a word for this, and, if so: what is it?

I've googled the following without any success:

> discontinuation of syllabi

> annulment of syllabi

> abolishment of syllabi

> cancellation of syllabi

> termination of syllabi

> retraction of syllabi

I do get a couple of hits for "the syllabus was discontinued" and "the syllabus was abolished" respectively, but not enough to convince me. So, is there another word I haven't thought of that would be better to use here?

Thank you!

Comment: Syllabus interruptus.

Comment: If the course is no longer taught, the syllabus simply becomes obsolete; it doesn't need to be 'abolished' 'terminated' etc. 'Discontinued' seems fine to me.

Comment: I'm curious about what concept your are trying to convey - an obsolete syllabus will generally just be abandoned, no one is likely to make much of an effort to delete it, unlike the course itself, which (probably) needs to be officially 'taken out of service'.

Comment: @MikeBrockington Haha, yes, you would think that, but apparently not at my uni... I'm translating a document detailing the process involved in abandoning a syllabus (as distinct from the process involved in terminating a course). It comprises 6 different steps, so, quite a big deal, apparently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Discontinued’ is the most appropriate though you wouldn’t really need to use it because as the course Itself has been discontinued it stands to reason that it’s contents (the syllabus) have too. You would only really need to refer to the syllabus independently if the course if it had been changed in some way